# How do I find a token in a file and then count the number of spaces that precede the token?

Tags: python

Using python, I am trying to search a file for a token, and then count the number of white spaces which precede that token to the start of the line.

So if the file is like this:

```
<index>

   <scm>
   </scm>

</index>
```

I want to find the number of spaces which precede `<scm>`

Comment: elaborate your *the start of the line*. Because there are two differend modes: single line mode and multiline mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for a *single-line* mode:

```
import itertools

with open('yourfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    txt = f.read()
    print(len(list(itertools.takewhile(lambda c: c.isspace(), txt[txt.index('<scm>')-1::-1]))))
```

The output:

```
5
```

---

- `txt[txt.index('<scm>')-1::-1]` - "reversed" slice from the position of string `<scm>` to the beginning of the text
- `itertools.takewhile(func, iterable)` - will accumulate values/characters from the input string(iterable) untill value/character is a whitespace (`c.isspace()`)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression. The number of spaces would be:

```
import re

with open('input.txt') as f_input:
    r = re.search('( +)' + re.escape("<scm>"), f_input.read(), re.S)
    print len(r.groups()[0])
```

Which would be `3`. Or the number of whitespace characters:

```
with open('input.txt') as f_input:
    r = re.search('(\s+)' + re.escape("<scm>"), f_input.read(), re.S)
    print len(r.groups()[0])
```

Which would be `5`

Answer (score 1):

If you meant just for the single line case, this would get you the preceeding spaces for that line

```
def get_preceeding_spaces(file_name, tag):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if tag in line:
                prefix = line.split(tag)[0]
                if re.match('\s*', prefix):
                    return len(prefix)

print(get_preceeding_spaces('test.html', '<scm>'))
```

returns for your file:

```
3
```